# How to write a Function to Decode a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am having an issue writing a function using loops that decodes the errors to bring the write word.

So for example when i write LATE, it produces TALE. And when i write "A" it sometimes comes as 8 and sometimes "B". To test the function we wrote works, we check for words like "L8KAOUL", "E8N8N8" , "UUIP".

Below in the table are the rules:
Hello,I am having an issue writing a function using loops that does the following,

| typed letter | produced letter |
| --- | --- |
| T | L |
| L | T |
| A | 8 |
| A | B |
| E | A |
| B | E |
| W | UU |

Here is what i tried:

```
result = ""
def decoder(misspelled_word):
    for letter in misspelled_word:
        if letter == "L":
            result += "T"
        elif letter == "T":
            result += "L"
        elif letter == 8 or letter == "B":
            result += "A"
        elif letter == "A":
            result += "E"
        elif letter == "E":
            result += "B"
        else:
            return misspelled_word
    return result
```

Can someone show me my mistake, As I am just starting out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 main problems in the code:

1. You return `misspelled_word` after not matching a special letter, instead of just adding it to the string.  I fixed this by changing the code in the `else` block.
2. You're checking if a string is equal to an int, when checking `letter == 8`.  Instead, check if the letter is the string representation of that same int (`letter = "8"`).
3. I moved the `result` initialization into the function so that it is reset whenever you call the function, instead of gaining more letters each time you call it.

Putting these together gives us the following:

```py
def decoder(misspelled_word):
    result = ""
    for letter in misspelled_word:
        if letter == "L":
            result += "T"
        elif letter == "T":
            result += "L"
        elif letter == "8" or letter == "B":
            result += "A"
        elif letter == "A":
            result += "E"
        elif letter == "E":
            result += "B"
        else:
            result += letter
    return result
```

Testing it shows good results:

```
decoder("L8KAOUL") -> TAKEOUT
decoder("E8N8N8") -> BANANA
```

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake. So hypothetically, When I type 'W' if it puts 'UU'. For example, for "WIP" it puts "UUIP" and i tried using the same principle and added the following on the code:
elif letter == "UU":
     result += "W"
Is there a reason that it is not working?

Comment: You can't match 2 characters when you're checking 1 character at a time.

Comment: So 
`if letter == "U":
                                                                                if letter == "U": result += "W" `
Brings WWIP. So are you saying the approach is different?